# SSLError : [Errno 1] _ssl.c:510: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

Tags: python-2.7, ssl, ssl-certificate, tweepy, pyopenssl

As we transfered twitter chatbot application (python code) from one server to another server. Both servers exactly mirror image. On new server I am getting error in initializing userstream in tweepy.

```
auth = OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN,ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
while 1:
    try:
        twitterStream = Stream(auth,listener())
        twitterStream.userstream() #I am getting error here
    except BaseException,e:
        print "Exception occured"
        print int(time.time())
        print "Restarting Stream"
        time.sleep(30)
        print e
        continue
```

Error is

> HTTPSConnectionPool(host='userstream.twitter.com', port=443): Max
>   retries exceeded with url: /1.1/user.json?delimited=lengted by
>   NewConnectionError(': Failed tlish a new connection: [Errno 110]
>   Connection timed out',))

&

> [Errno 1] _ssl.c:510: error:14090086:SSL
>   routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

**Which configuration I have to make on new server to run this smoothly?**

My new server has below details ------ OS – Ubuntu 14.04.5 ------ Python - 2.7.6 ----- Open SSL Version - OpenSSL 1.0.1f ----- requests (2.11.1) ----- tweepy (3.5.0) ----- pyOpenSSL (0.13)

Comment: You probably need to make sure your new server trusts as CA the entity that signed the server certificate, which is *DigiCert Inc.*

Comment: Yes new server has same digicert certificates as old one but still I am not able to run this program. Any other solution to this ?

Comment: Thank you Issue Resolved. :)